# send button value to Jquery AJAX with onclick()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

is it possible to send a value from button to Jquery AJAX with onclick function ?
I have tried something like this code, but not working.
There is nothing on console log.

html

```
<button type="button" class="hapus_krs" onclick="hapus_krs(this.value)" value="1">x</button> 
<button type="button" class="hapus_krs" onclick="hapus_krs(this.value)" value="2">x</button>
<button type="button" class="hapus_krs" onclick="hapus_krs(this.value)" value="n">x</button>
```

script

```
function hapus_krs() {
    var formData = {
        'id_mhs': $(this).val()
    };
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?=base_url()?>akademik/hapus_krs',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            encode: true
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke the function with `onclick="hapus_krs(this.value)"`, you are already passing the button value to the function as parameter:

```
function hapus_krs(value) {
    var formData = {
        'id_mhs': value
    };
}
```

[Unobtrusive JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) version:

```
<button type="button" class="hapus_krs" value="1">x</button> 
<button type="button" class="hapus_krs" value="2">x</button>
<button type="button" class="hapus_krs" value="n">x</button>

$('button.hapus_krs').click(function() {
    var formData = {
        'id_mhs': this.value // $(this).val() also works but it's unnecessary to invoke another jQuery call
    };
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot, the first answer it's work. I am going to try the Unobtrusive JS version see if it's better.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/60qu6mev/

```js
$('.hapus_krs').click(function(){
var formData = {
  'id_mhs': $(this).attr('value')
};
console.log(formData);
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<?=base_url()?>akademik/hapus_krs',
      data: formData,
      dataType: 'json',
      encode: true
  })
  .done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="hapus_krs"  value="1">x</button> 
<button type="button" class="hapus_krs" value="2">x</button>
<button type="button" class="hapus_krs" value="n">x</button>
```

I have removed the **onclick** from HTML, rather used a **jQuery** **click** **event** to handle ajax call & retrieve value from button

Comment: what is the disadvantage of using onclick() function on HTML ?

Comment: @BillyOrigin There is no disadvantage... I just made it so that JS code will be in JS file & HTML will be free..

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful when playing with `this`. In your code, `this` might not refer the the button that has been clicked.

In addition, you are passing a `this.value` as a parameter and yet you are not using it. So your function should look like the following:

```js
function hapus_krs(value) {
    var formData = {
        'id_mhs': value
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?=base_url()?>akademik/hapus_krs',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        encode: true
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
};
```